# Security footage comes up while using screen share from iPhone to smartTV

Tags: iphone, samsung-smart-tv, broadcasting, screensharing

I was watching a movie on a website and the player was VidMoly. I have started screen casting it from my iPhone to Samsung smart tv. Movie was going on as expected but after a couple of minutes the stream on the TV suddenly changed into a security footage of a room in a house where there was a man hanging on his computer. Me and my friends tried different websites and different phones this only occurred when we were using VidMoly player. I have tried to track networking on my phone by using web debugging applications but so far do not know what may be the cause of this? Does anybody have any idea about this?